# File Upload in Update Panel within the user control not working?

Tags: asp.net

I need to use file upload in user control. user control exists in update panel .
File upload not working FileUpload HasFile always return false

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upanel" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc3:Assignment ID="assignment" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>

        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605109/button-event-doesnt-fire-inside-update-panel-for-fileupload

Comment: Thank your response Aishvarya , this update panel i use as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344032/how-to-use-file-upload-in-jquery-modal-popup

Comment: @Aishvarya- Your link have not any up answer, How can he will find good solution there?

Comment: @Wella - You need to add a `PostBackTrigger` for your `UploadControl` because it is inside an update panel. (Maybe you need an `AsyncPostBackTrigger`)

Comment: This update panel i use in jquery modal popup when i register postback it will close the modal

Comment: @RameshRajendran Thank you , My requirement is file upload in jquery modal popup. Please refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20344032/how-to-use-file-upload-in-jquery-modal-popup

Comment: @Wella, Please take a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375298/asyncfileupload-in-jquery-modal-popup